# Who is invoked in gayatri mantra?

Tags: gayatri-mantra

Gayatri mantra is famous all over. 'om bhur bhuvaha svah tat savitur varenyam bhargo devasya......'  Who is invoked in the famous gayatri mantra? I mean which god or goddess is invoked.

Comment: Savitri-Devata is invoked. You can take that for the Sun-God or Parama-Brahman who is the Primal Source of the seven lokas

Comment: @Pratimaputra isnt the Param jyoti its addressed in Gayatri mantra? Its the jyoti linga - isvara I think!.